# Why does this line return sum of integers 1-10?

Tags: perl

I'd like to understand how `unpack` is returning the sum in the given perl one-liner.

I've looked at `pack` man page and mostly understood that it is simply formatting the given array into a `scalar` of `ten` doubles.

However, I couldn't find proper documentation for `unpack` with `%123`. Looking for help here.

```
print unpack "%123d*" , pack( "d*", (1..10));
```

This line correctly outputs `55` which is `1+2+3+...+10`.

Comment: My guess for the downvote you ask about: the page for [unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) is very short and practically the only thing discussed is precisely the `%` prefix, explained in detail.  Thus the statement "_couldn't find proper documentation_" can rub the wrong way.  Having said that, I still find the question reasonable, given the arbitrary `123` used. (And ff _that_ is indeed what puzzled you, while you have looked at the docs, you could have phrased that sentenced more carefully, to convey that you _did_ see the docs but don't get `123`.)

Comment: @zdim Right, my explanation does look a bit sloppy and I didn't explain much of what I knew about `unpack`. I now clearly see how that part of my post could piss off many awesome people haha; I'll make sure future posts include key detail like these. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [perldoc -f unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.0/functions/unpack.html):

> In addition to fields allowed in pack(), you may prefix a field with a % to indicate that you want a <number>-bit checksum of the items instead of the items themselves.

Thus `%123d*` means to add all the input integers `1..10` and then take the first 123 bit of this result in order to construct the *"<number>-bit checksum"*. Note that `%8d*` or just `%d*` (which is equivalent to `%16d*`) would suffice too given that the sum is small enough.

Comment: Ahh, 55 does fit in 8 bits so he randomly put 123 there. Got it completely! Thank you so much :)